# HTML is escaped if called from assets or content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, escaping

I just faced with a problem that my coffee code is not processed as I expected. So, the following code

```
#app/views/smth/edit.slim
- content_for :js_scripts
  coffee:
    $ ->
      $("#destination-id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pages') %>")

.smth-page
  #some slim-html-code here
```

produces nothing, but `<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pages') %>` written as a plain text in my view. Not a partial, just plain text with this code

I thought "OK, I move it to another file and place it to `app/assets/javascript`." Also, there was some logic, so it was prettier to do so. OK, I moved it, like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/vid/smth.coffee
class Vid.Smth
  constructor: =>
    $("#destination-id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pages') %>")

#app/views/smth/edit.slim
- content_for :js_scripts
  coffee:
    $ ->
      new Vid.Smth()
```

but nothing changed.

Googling showed a lot of questions without answers and advices like

- replacing single quoted with double quotes and vise versa;
- replacing `escape_javascript` with `j`;
- use `raw`;
- use `.js`, `.erb`, `.js.coffee.erb`, *etc.* in filename

And so on. None helped.

Then I remembered doing the same thing and getting it work. After some hours of investigating, copying and pasting, I ended up putting this code to partial and rendering it from view:

```
# app/views/smth/edit.slim
...
= render :partial 'test'

#app/views/smth/_test.coffee
$("#destination-id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pages') %>")
```

and that did the trick! The partial finally rendered.

So, the question is: why it behaves so? Is that a bug or a feature, or a consequent thing that follows from rendering rules?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Try to summarize with code what you were doing before, and what you are doing now.

Comment: @ArslanAli I added smth. Hope that helps, cause I'm not really sure, what do you mean: anything's describes (seems to me so :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, I did something wrong over there, so the only thing I needed was `javascript_tag` to wrap the JS code that I want to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ruby script in file ending with *.js is a pure javascript. 
You should change your file endings with *.js.erb or *.js.coffee.erb
and will be able to use rails helpers

Comment: I do not use .js. Is it written somewhere here?

Comment: As you can see in my question, no, I don't need this. Putting the same string in file with .coffee extention does it. Also I have some logic there, and it fails to run when I add `.erb` to the name of the file. I saw all of these recommendations, they do not work.